# Implementing tabs and menu in a single page in ionic4

Tags: ionic4

I have a project which is done in ionic1 with tabs and menu in the same page.I want to implement the same in  ionic4.
The existing problem in ionic4 is that, those pages being redirected on clicking the menu are not supporting tabs. I am not able to include the code for menu and tab in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

you can flow this tutorial [Combine side menu, tabs and login page with Ionic 4](http://meumobi.github.io/ionic/2018/11/13/side-menu-tabs-login-page-ionic4.html)
that implements side-menu and tabs on the same page

another useful tutorial is [here](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-4-tabs-side-menu/) from IonicAcademy